# Terminology of Accuracy

Tags: terminology

If a measuring instrument, say, a ruler, has a resolution of 1cm, the reading of any object is accurate to +/- 0.5 of a centimetre.  Is there any terminology to describe 0.5 in this context?  I’m tempted to call it uncertainty (of 0.5), but I’m not sure this is right.

Comment: The term "error" or "maximum error" is commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

> The term "error" or "maximum error" is commonly used. –
> user247327

Comment: Does [this](https://xkcd.com/2696/) help?